Poetry permission denied
This is the content of my dockerfile. I am trying to dockerise a fastapi application but I have been running into an error for a long time.
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

# Comments are provided throughout this file to help you get started.
# If you need more help, visit the Dockerfile reference guide at
# https://docs.docker.com/go/dockerfile-reference/

# Want to help us make this template better? Share your feedback here: https://forms.gle/ybq9Krt8jtBL3iCk7

ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.10.12
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}-slim as base

# Prevents Python from writing pyc files.
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Keeps Python from buffering stdout and stderr to avoid situations where
# the application crashes without emitting any logs due to buffering.
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1


# Ensure /root/.local/bin is in the PATH
ENV PATH=/root/.local/bin:$PATH

# Working directory
WORKDIR /app
       
# Create a non-privileged user that the app will run under.
# See https://docs.docker.com/go/dockerfile-user-best-practices/
ARG UID=10001
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    appuser


# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*



# Install virtualenv
RUN pip install virtualenv

# Create and activate a virtual environment
RUN virtualenv /opt/venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"



# Install poetry
RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 - && \
    mv /root/.local/bin/poetry /usr/local/bin/poetry 
    
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/poetry 
RUN chown -R appuser:appuser /usr/local/bin/poetry


# Copy dependency files
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ./


# Install dependencies with Poetry
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
    && poetry install --no-root


# Switch to the non-privileged user to run the application.
USER appuser


# Set up Database
#RUN /home/appuser/.local/bin/poetry run bash ./prestart.sh

# Copy the source code into the container.
COPY . .

# Expose the port that the application listens on.a
EXPOSE 8000

# Run the application.
CMD poetry run uvicorn app.main:app --reload

The error message I get is server-1  | /bin/sh: 1: poetry: Permission denied. I don't know how to solve this. The resources online said to use a virtual environment different from the poetry's own. I am still getting the same error

Try to use following Dockerfile:
# Build stage
FROM python:3.10.12-slim-buster as builder
ENV PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off \
    POETRY_PATH=/opt/poetry \
    VENV_PATH=/opt/venv
ENV PATH="$POETRY_PATH/bin:$VENV_PATH/bin:$PATH"
RUN apt-get update \
   && apt-get install -y \
        curl \
        gcc \
        libpq-dev \
    && curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | POETRY_HOME=$POETRY_PATH python3 -
RUN python -m venv $VENV_PATH \
    && pip install --upgrade pip \
    && poetry config virtualenvs.create false
RUN apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ./
RUN . $VENV_PATH/bin/activate \
    && poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi --no-dev -vvv


# Runtime stage
FROM python:3.10.12-slim-buster as runtime
ENV VENV_PATH=/opt/venv \
    PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH" \
    PYTHONPATH=/app \
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder $VENV_PATH $VENV_PATH
COPY . ./
EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT uvicorn --host 0.0.0.0 --no-access-log --reload asgi:app


Please don't apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* in a separate layer - it doesn't give the space cleanup you're looking for! Once previous RUN ended, everything is fixed in the layer, and later removal won't shrink the image size. Merge this with RUN that does apt-get {uodate,install} or remove altogether (since you don't copy it to final image), but stop voodoo programming removing that "just in case".
